# loading ca certificate which is CRL is list is working fine

Tags: certificate

with openssl command we generated ca certificate((serial No: 1234)) loaded it in one program Program 1.
it is contacted and working fine,
now i loaded new certificate to Program 1(serial No: abcd) and revoked old certificate(serial No: 1234).
certificate serial Number is present in CRL List (serial No: 1234).
is if load again old certificate(serial No: 1234) to Program 1. it is expected to give handshake failure because old certificate is already revoked and it is present in CRL List.

but it is working fine. we are able to connect to Program 1.

even thought certificate is present in crl List why it is working fine ?

Comment: Depending on its defaults and settings a program may ignore revocation status or other invalidity reasons for certificates. Thus, you should check the documentation and configuration of *Program 1*.

Comment: on same program 1 if i load new certificate, revoke that certificate then that program will give SSL Error. only for one certificate i am facing that issue.

Comment: Is maybe the old crl (in which the certificate has not yet been revoked) still valid and cached somewhere?

Comment: but if load again different certificate and revoke it. after loading revoked certificate i am getting sSSL error. 
Here  issue with only one certificate. if load same one certificate 10 times and revoke it again and again also it is working fine.

Comment: Maybe the certificate isn't revoked after all but merely a similarly named one. Maybe there is an error in the CRL. Maybe there is a bug in *Program 1* triggered by your special certificate. ... I'm afraid with that little, very unspecific information you gave all one can do amounts to pure guesswork.